# I need to get the letter from a word

Tags: c, arrays, string, character, letter

I tried this code but at the `for` loop it seems to do nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{

    char word[100];
    char suf [100];
    int i,j,k = 0;
    char a [100];

    printf("Enter the word: \n");
    gets(word);
    printf("\n");



    for (i = strlen(word); i < 0; i--)
            {
                 a[i] = word[i];
                 printf("%s",a);

            }
}
```

Example Output:

> >> Enter the word: Program
>
> >> m
>
> >> am
>
> >> ram
>
> >> gram
>
> >> ogram
>
> >> rogram

Comment: Please read Someone answered my question! What to do now? http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers , and consider accepting one of the answers to your questions

Answer (score 1):

Using pointer arithmetic would probably be the easiest way to do this; you won't even need a temporary buffer:

```
for (i = strlen(word) - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    printf("%s\n", word + i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man...I got stucked at the last step...didn't know how to manage that thing...thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**ALTERNATIVE** : Use a pointer approach :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char word[100];

    printf("Enter the word: \n");
    gets(word);
    printf("\n");
    char *ptr;
    int len = (int)strlen(word) ;

    for (int i = len -1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        ptr = &word[i];
        printf("%s\n",ptr);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation :**

Say the string you entered is `program`
Now, the index ranges from 0 to 6 here, and not 7.
In your code, you are starting with `i = strlen(word)` which is wrong. You should start with `i = strlen(word) -1`.

Also, you should decrement till the value of `i` is greater than `0` - not less as in your case `i < 0`.

**SUGGESTIONS :**

Do not use `void main(……)`. Use `int main(…)`. The former may not be supported on all compliers.